# Dev Container : bind user?

Tags: docker, permissions

I have a very basic Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

ARG USER=latex
ARG UID=1000
ARG GID=1000
ARG PW=latex

RUN useradd -m ${USER} --uid=${UID} && echo "${USER}:${PW}" | \
    chpasswd
USER ${UID}:${GID}
WORKDIR /home/${USER}
```

If I build it I notice the workdirectory belongs to `latex`:

```
$ test docker build .devcontainer/Dockerfile
$ docker run -it badbeef $(pwd -P):/home/latex /bin/bash
latex@badbeef:~$ ls -al
drwxr-xr-x 2 latex latex 4096 Jun 29 18:52 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root  root  4096 Jun 29 18:52 ..
drwxrwxrwx 1 latex latex 512  Jun 29 18:51 .devcontainer
```

Now I try to open it into a Dev Container into VsCode. Here my `devcontainer.json`

```
{
    "name": "merci-la-vie",
    "dockerFile": "Dockerfile",
    "remoteUser": "latex"
}
```

From the console tab I get this:

```
$ whoami
latex
$ ls -al
total 4
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root  512 Jun 29 18:28 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jun 29 18:58 ..
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root  512 Jun 29 18:51 .devcontainer
```

Why is the current folder owned by latex?

Comment: This code doesn't appear to work or is missing pieces. What is the `test` command in `test docker build .devcontainer/Dockerfile`?  What are you trying to do with the `$(pwd -P):/home/latex` part of `docker run -it badbeef $(pwd -P):/home/latex /bin/bash`?  Are you actually tagging your build with `badbeef`, if so I don't see it...

Comment: @kthompso badbeef a dummy hash for this build. I didn't include the real one.